# FIRApp configure fails w/ "Configure Durable Deep Link fails"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Just started w/ Firebase and the first call of the first app fails -- yeah!
   [FIRApp configure] throws an exception: "Configure Durable Deep Link fails".   There's a GoogleService-info.plist but affect no entry for deep links.  Tried toggling a few of the IS_* fields but no luck.
   Is this something to be setup on the Dashboard?  Are the Pod/Frameworks in github somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

there's a duplicate question from @mskobe

by messing around w/ the PodFile I narrowed it down to removing:
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
not sure if it's an order or combination of other pods/operations.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error! It probably has something to do with your `GoogleServices-info.plist` file missing an important entry (probably `API_KEY` or `CLIENT_ID`).

You can most likely fix this by just re-downloading the `GoogleServices-info.plist` file again. Go to the Firebase console, select your project, click the little gear icon, select "Project settings" then for your iOS app, download the plist file again.

Delete the old one from Xcode, drag the new one in, and you should be good to go.